# Haskell: Bound variables within where clause

Tags: haskell

What is the scope of a bound variable? Why can't I access it from within where clause?
For instance, in this example:

```
someFunc x y = do
  let a = x + 10
  b <- someAction y
  return subFunc
  where
    subFunc = (a * 2) + (b * 3)
```

Here, the subFunc can see a but not b.
Why can't I use bound variable within where clause? Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because it could lead to inconsistencies. Imagine this code:

```
printName = do
  print fullName
  firstName <- getLine
  lastName <- getLine
  return ()
  where
    fullName = firstName ++ " " + lastName
```

This code wouldn't work, and because of these kinds of situations, the use of bound variables is limited to the part of a `do` block that follows the actual binding. This becomes clear when desugaring the above code:

```
printName =
  print fullName >>
  getLine >>= (\ firstName ->
    getLine >>= (\ lastName ->
      return ()
    )
  )
  where
    fullName = firstName ++ " " ++ lastName
```

Here, one can see that the variables `firstName` and `lastName` are not in scope in the `where` clause, and that they cannot be used in any definitions in that clause.